# PHP Help assigning cabin to group according to the capacity of the cabin

Tags: php

I'm developing a simple booking system and i want to assign cabins to groups according to the capacity of the cabin, so far i achieved to split the group in smaller groups if the cabin does not have the capacity for the entire group.

```
<?php
$group = 14;

$cabinsArray = array("1"=>15,"2"=>3,"3"=>8);

$cantCab = count($cabinsArray);

echo "Available cabins: ".$cantCab."<br>";

$cabins = 0;

foreach($cabinsArray as $cabin => $capacity){
    $group = $group - $capacity;
    $cabins++;
    if($group < 0){
        break;
    }
}

if($group > 0){
    echo 'No cabins available, remains '.$grupo.' people out';
}else if($cabins > $cantCab){
    echo 'No cabins available';
}else{
    echo ceil($cabins);
}
?>
```

The issue comes when it assigns the cabins, if my group is of 24 people and my cabins capacity order is 15,3,8 instead of select the 15 and the 8 it selects the 3 cabins.

How can i select the cabins according to the capacity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sort the `$cabinsArray` from highest to lowest before you loop?

Comment: Thanks but if i do this then it will assign 2 cabins of 15 for 18 people, cause the array of cabins i putted in the OP is only a reference

Comment: Oh, are the keys from that array the amount of cabins and the values are the capacity of said cabin?

Comment: So you have one cabin that has 15 capacity, 2 cabins that have 3 capacity, 3 cabins with 8 capacity?

Comment: No, the key defines the cabin number as it can be 365 and the value is the capacity. i've tried verifying if the capacity is higher than the group to assign the cabin but it always returns me the wrong number of cabins assigned. I suppose that is because of the starting index of the array and the $cabins counter set to 0, i tried setting it to 1 with same result

Comment: So cabin number 1 has capacity of 15, cabin number 2 has capacity of 3, etc., correct?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I think you need a fairly complex algorithm to determine best matches. If you are still around I think I have one almost worked out.

Comment: Thanks! I have almost 3 hours trying to decypher how to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90580/discussion-between-douglas-roos-and-rasclatt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is just a starting point. The algorithm would probably be much more complex to figure out how to split up capacities but here is a starting point. You could just use `array_pop()` or `end()` to get the lowest from the `$new` array:

```
$group          =   14;
$cabinsArray    =   array("32"=>3,"4"=>14,"200"=>8,"12"=>10,"6"=>4);
arsort($cabinsArray);
$cabinNums      =   array_keys($cabinsArray);
$cabinCaps      =   array_values($cabinsArray);
$highest        =   $cabinCaps[0];
$diff           =   $group - $highest;

$i = 0;
foreach($cabinCaps as $key => $value) {
        if(($value >= $diff))
            $new[$cabinNums[$key]]  =   $cabinCaps[$key];
        $i++;
    }

print_r($new);
print_r($highest);
```

Comment: Thanks, finally i gotted and it was easier than i though, using mysql of course, i will let the answer here in the OP